# Does "Evening Get" correspond to a real-life television show?

Tags: japanese-language, culture, orange

In chapter 2 of *Orange*, Hagita tells his friends that he has go home to watch *Evening Get*. The text outside the speech bubbles explains it as:

> *Evening Get*! It's a Nagano TV show that starts at 4:30. Ryuta Mine's gonna be on today's show.

Ryuta Mine appears to be [a real Japanese actor](http://asianwiki.com/Ryuta_Mine) from Nagano prefecture. Similarly, in ch.5*, Naho and Kakeru's friends give excuses for why they cannot walk home together with Naho and Kakeru. Hagita's excuse that he is going to watch *Evening Get*. Outside the speak bubble is:

> They're doing a story on Mino Monta's son …

Mino Monta also appears to be [a real-life personality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monta_Mino) in Japan.

With these two instances in mind, does *Evening Get* correspond to a real-life television show? I have tried a bunch of internet searches but have no found anything of use so far. Perhaps someone who can read the original Japanese text might have more luck?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, [ゆうがたGet!](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%86%E3%81%86%E3%81%8C%E3%81%9FGet!) (*Yuugata Get!*, Evening Get!) is a real-life TV show.**

It's broadcasted by [TV. Shinshu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TV._Shinshu)  located in Nagano prefecture since April 5, 1999. Based on the broadcast schedule list on the Wikipedia, the show started at 4:30 on the weekdays in:

- April 1999 - September 2000 under the name of 「陽司★美恵子 ゆうがたGet!」, and
- March 2010 - March 2014 under the name of 「情報ワイド ゆうがたGet!」

---

As already mentioned on the question, [Ryuta Mine](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B3%B0%E7%AB%9C%E5%A4%AA) is also a real-life person. Based on the list of appearance on the Wikipedia, he appeared once every month on Wednesday in:

- 「情報ワイド ゆうがたGet!」, and
- 「ゆうがたGet!」

which means the story took place in between 2010-2014 instead of 1999-2000.

---

Regarding the episode of Mino Monta's son, I couldn't find the specific date/episode. <s>but it's probably regarding</s>

> the arrest on 13 September [2013] of his 31-year-old son, Yuto Minorikawa (御法川 雄斗), who was charged with stealing a man's bag on the street in Tokyo.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia - Monta Mino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monta_Mino)</sub>

Considering the publication month of chapter 5, the episode (if it existed) should be broadcasted before August 2012.

---

<sub>P.S. it might be possible that the author took the events that had occurred recently at that time since the manga was serialized in 2012-2015.</sub>

Comment: FWIW we find out in chapter 20 that the beginning of the manga is set in April of 2012. I'm not sure how to reconcile (if at all) the incident with Mino's son with that: by all accounts, a _regular_ monthly publication of the manga would imply that chapter 5 was published _before_ the incident, if publication began in March 2012. But maybe there were breaks in the publication along the way.

Comment: @Maroon you're right. The theory on Mino Monta's son is too weak. [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AE%E3%82%82%E3%82%93%E3%81%9F#.E5.AE.B6.E6.97.8F.E3.83.BB.E7.B8.81.E6.88.9A) on Mino Monta stated that he has 3 children; 2 sons & 1 daughter. However, I couldn't find any episode with either son. OTOH, apparently *Orange* serialization had a break, but that's after ch. 8, so ch. 5 was indeed published in 2012.